# How do I get from a Google AMP page to that actual webpage in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I don't want to disable AMP completely, but if I'm on an AMP page sometimes I want to get to the original webpage. There used to be a link to get there but that seems to be gone now. How do I get to the original web page?

Comment: See https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-find-non-google-amp-web-pages

Answer (score 1):

- Some AMP pages show the link to go the original source ([example](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.theverge.com/platform/amp/2018/3/8/17095078/google-amp-accelerated-mobile-page-announcement-standard-web-packaging-urls))
  , while others don't. I am not sure why this happens.
- I couldn't find any flags (`chrome://flags/`)
  that forces AMP pages to show the link (on a PC, this seems to do the trick) . But Chrome in *desktop* worked for me :

  - If the AMP page appears in a Google search, changing to desktop mode removes the AMP pages as you can see by the missing lightning bolt icons that represent AMP pages. See [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+verge+Google+amp&oq=the+verge+Google+amp&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30.17053j0j7&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) in mobile and desktop modes.
  - If you are already on the AMP page change it to desktop mode. You can test with the link in first bullet point.

I read about this in some blog, which I can't find now to link. It attributed to desktop mode overriding AMP, since AMP is basically for mobile version (Accelerated *Mobile* Page).

Comment: Did this fix your problem or I wonder if some AMP sites don't respect this method. Curious

Answer (score 1):

Click on this link icon to get to the original webpage:

[image]